# How do I bind an index number to an event using jQuery's each function?

Tags: jquery, dynamic, binding, each

I have a function that I want to execute with a particular number. That number is dynamic, depending on the number of elements in a **ul** element. In this example, let's say there are 10 **li** elements.

```
function alertThisNum(itemNum) {
    alert(itemNum);
}

$('ul li').each(function(index) {
    itemNum = index + 1;
    $("a#" + itemNum).bind("click", function() {
        alertThisNum(itemNum);
    });
});
```

The problem is, *itemNum* is always the last number. It binds the number 10 to all the links.

How do I get **a.1** to alert "1", **a.2** to alert "2", and so on?

Comment: you are alerting the last value of itemNum are you not? can you post the resultant html aswell please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Localize your `itemNum` variable by preceding this line `itemNum = index + 1;` with the `var` keyword:

```
var itemNum = index + 1;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JAAulde/FnSmA/

Comment: Thank you for the excellent example. I have to use jsfiddle more!

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare a **local** variable in your `each` callback using the `var` keyword.

Right now, all of your callbacks are sharing the same `itemNum` **global**.